# Email on a cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I am facing an issue and I just can't find the right answer.

I currently have an mail server fully functional on a vps. I want to move this mail server to another vps wich has cPanel installed. The problem is that my main domain is pointing my first server and I don't know hoe to configure the cPanel domain for mail hosting. I have changed my MX records so that the emails are pointed to my new server. But what domain should I give to cPanel? If I am making a subdomain for my cpanel server, my emails would be user@subdomain.domain.com. But I want them to remain lile user@domain.com

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your domain (domain.ext)  to cpanel first. If you just want to host only mail on this cpanel server, point your MX to cpanel server.

Keel this in mind:
1. In DNS zone, add A record for mail.domain.ext pointing to new server
2.  Point MX to mail.domain.ext

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, whenever you're creating the email address itself, under the master account you must select which domain to make the email with. There you can choose in a drop down menu whether you want it @subdomain.domain.ext or @domain.ext.

Comment: So I should configure my cPanel domain as my main domain name even if this is pointing only email to cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

If you will create the email account for sub-domain then it will look like email_address@sub_domain.com. It's not possible to replace it with main domain_name.